# Ошибка при возвращении в методе Java

Tags: java, ооп

Ошибка в `return getDist`. Eclipse хочет объявление отдельного класса для `getDist`.

FILE1 LOCATION_TESTER:

```
package Gefest;

public class LocationTester{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleLocation ucsd =
                new SimpleLocation(32.9, -117.2);

        SimpleLocation lima =
                new SimpleLocation(-12.0, -77.0);

        System.out.println(ucsd.distance(lima));
    }
}
```

FILE 2 SIMPLE_LOCATION:

```
package Gefest;

public class SimpleLocation{
    public double latitude; // data for GEO
    public double longitude;

    public SimpleLocation(double lat, double lon) {
        this.latitude = lat;
        this.longitude= lon;
    }

    public double distance(SimpleLocation other) {
         return getDist(this.latitude, this.longitude,other.latitude, other.longitude); 
    }
}
```

Я знаю, что у меня нет этого класа. Мне нужно знать, как вернуть те же параметры не используя клас.

Comment: Добавьте сам метод getDist

Comment: Вы в  return  функции distance используете функцию getDist которая у вас нигде не определена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `distance` просит вернуть тип `double`, а вы ему подсовываете метод, которого у вас нет вообще.

return **getDist**(this.latitude, this.longitude,other.latitude, other.longitude);

```
public double getDist(double a,double b,double c,double d){
     //Ваши операции над числами
     // Допустим :
     return (a-b)+(c+d);
}
```

Ну а ещё, `distance` - это **не конструктор.** Подкрепите теорию, и возвращайтесь снова )